# Python 2.7 json.load() wrong encoded umlaut characters

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I get string from request, that contain character ñ. the code of this character before json.load() is \xc3\xb1 after that method my string transform to dict and current character had code u'\xf1.  i can not insert this character in mongodb.

```
strings in documents must be valid UTF-8:
```

but if i try save munually \xc3\xb1 instead u'\xf1 that all are saved good.

whole code

```
 try:
    # Load params arriving as json data
    enc = 'UTF-8'  
    print 'lal'
    params = json.loads(request.get_data())
    print params
    # Check all parameters
    customer_id = params.get('customer', '')
    check_credentials(customer_id, params.get('apikey', ''))
    collection_id = params.get('collection', '')
    if not collection_id or not str(collection_id).isdigit():
        raise Exception, "Invalid collection"
    train_records = params.get('train', [])         
    if not train_records:
        raise Exception, "Train records are needed in the 'train' parameter"
    # Store the trained classifier in database for a better performance
    train_records = map(lambda x: x.values(), train_records)
    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train_records)
    pk = '%s__%i' % (customer_id, collection_id)
    data = {'_id': pk, 'customer': customer_id, 'collection': collection_id, 'classifier': pickle.dumps(cl), 'train':train_records}
    if db.classifiers.find_one({'_id': pk}):           
        db.classifiers.update({'_id': pk}, data)
    else:
        db.classifiers.insert(data)
    # Asyncronously increase usage count in order to check rate limits
    gevent.spawn(increase_usage, customer_id)

except Exception as e:
    print e
```

json request

```
{
  "apikey": "yt1uy23123123123",
  "customer": 111111,
  "collection": 111111,
  "train": [
    {
      "text": "ñ",
      "label": "pos"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you post the whole code?an example of the JSON file?

Comment: Probably I should recognize the version of Python that you are using from what you've said (I'd guess 2.x if pressed).  Because Python treats unicode differently in 2.x and 3.x I suggest that you edit your post to indicate which version of Python you're using.  If you've not already done so, you could do some self help by reading the applicable [Unicode](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html) [HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: Nice job of improving your question, I'll give you a thumbs up for that.  BTW, if you include `@<username>` in response comments, the user will be notified that a reply is available.

Comment: So what's that `enc = 'UTF-8'` supposed to do here?